# How to validate a FIX message against Fix dictionary in QuickFix/J?

Tags: java, quickfix, fix-protocol, quickfixj

If validation is on in QuickFix/J, the received FIX message is validated against the FIX dictionary configured for Fix engine.

> **ValidateIncomingMessage**| Allow to bypass the message validation
>   (against the dictionary). Default is "Y".

Is there any utility class or method present in QuickFix/J which provides me this functionality to validate a sample Fix message against a Fix dictionary?

Answer (score 3):

You want to use DataDictionary.validate()

```
            DataDictionary dataDictionary = new DataDictionary( pathToDictionary );
            Message quickfixMessage = new Message( message, dataDictionary );
            dataDictionary.validate( quickfixMessage );
```

where message is the fix message. QuickfixJ includes some dictionaries in the etc folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a specific `String` that you would like to validate, `quickfix.Message` has a constructor that lets you do this:

```
public Message(String string,
       DataDictionary dd,
       boolean validate)
        throws InvalidMessage
```

And can be used like this, for example.

```
DataDictionary myDict = new DataDictionary(dictionaryPathHere);
Message myMessage = new Message(messageString, myDict, true);
// If this doesn't throw an exception, the message was successfully validated against the dictionary.
```

Comment: This will only validate repeating groups in the message against the dictionary then validate the checksum. It will NOT validate non group fields against the dictionary.

Comment: Just to support above comment ... https://github.com/quickfix/quickfix/blob/12ae2153f6e91c9bf30cc53e83742d983eec66ff/src/C%2B%2B/Message.cpp#L597