# QuickFIX/N FIX data dictionary validation

Tags: quickfix, quickfixn

I have a FIX protocol solution that is built on QuickFIXn.Core v1.11.0, which generally works fine, establishing a session and exchanging admin messages, using FIX.4.4 version. But when it comes to App messages, my partner is using custom message structure, which causes an error that resembles failing data dictionary validation.

When I manually validate the message against the data dictionary and use this code, everything looks good:

```
var path = @"path_to_the_xml_dictionary";
DataDictionary dt = new(path);
var message = "custom_message";
Message m = new Message(message, dt, true);
dt.Validate(m, "FIX.4.4", "8");
m.FromString(message, true, dt, dt);
```

What is odd is that after this error FIX client immediately sends a logout request with `58=Incorrect BeginString (FIX.4.4)` as a reason, indicating there is something wrong with the data dictionary, but nothing more than that.

Full error stack trace, from the logs:

> QuickFix.UnsupportedVersion: Incorrect BeginString (FIX.4.4)     at
> QuickFix.DefaultMessageFactory.Create(String beginString, String
> msgType, Int32 groupCounterTag)     at
> QuickFix.Message.SetGroup(StringField grpNoFld, String msgstr, Int32
> pos, FieldMap fieldMap, IGroupSpec groupDD, DataDictionary
> sessionDataDictionary, DataDictionary appDD, IMessageFactory
> msgFactory)     at QuickFix.Message.FromString(String msgstr, Boolean
> validate, DataDictionary sessionDD, DataDictionary appDD,
> IMessageFactory msgFactory, Boolean ignoreBody)     at
> QuickFix.Message.FromString(String msgstr, Boolean validate,
> DataDictionary sessionDD, DataDictionary appDD, IMessageFactory
> msgFactory)     at QuickFix.MessageBuilder.Build()     at
> QuickFix.Session.Next(MessageBuilder msgBuilder)

Comment: I could use this validation approach https://stackoverflow.com/q/47782231/8483576 but is there anything built-in, or a better way?

Comment: Where did you get the BeginString error? On reception of a message? Could you show an example message and your config?

Comment: Are you on linux?  This might be caused by https://github.com/connamara/quickfixn/pull/663, which is in the recently-released 1.11.0.

Comment: @GrantBirchmeier We are using Windows.  I see my NewOrderSingle message going, their ExecutionReport message incoming and then and exception happens inside the code, so the logout message is automatically sen from my side, with the text (58=Incorrect BeginString (FIX.4.4).

Comment: @ChristophJohn I tried hardcoding message and data dictionary and using Validate method from the existing stack overflow question I mentioned in my first comment. Although it passes Validation, once in production I get this exception:
QuickFix.UnsupportedVersion: Incorrect BeginString (FIX.4.4)     at QuickFix.DefaultMessageFactory.Create(String beginString, String msgType, Int32 groupCounterTag)     at QuickFix.Message.SetGroup(StringField grpNoFld, String msgstr, Int32 pos, FieldMap fieldMap, IGroupSpec groupDD, DataDictionary sessionDataDictionary, DataDictionary appDD, (....)

Comment: Is your production also running on a Windows case-insensitive filesystem?

Comment: @GrantBirchmeier I will have to check with my infrastructure colleagues, could you provide any more details about your question?

Comment: The bug I linked above is related to an file-case mistake in the code, which causes this error message on case-sensitive file systems.  (It is fixed in the just-released 1.11.0)  If your prod is linux or unix, then it sounds like this could be it.

Comment: @GrantBirchmeier thank you for pointing that out. I will update the Quickfix version and let you know the results.

Comment: @GrantBirchmeier updated to v1.11.0 but nothing changed from just that. We thought it was due to our partner's ExecutionReport message, but after removing NoStipulations group from both the dictionary and the message that we are sending NewOrderSingle (D) we started losing the error. Unfortunately after adding additional fields to their message we again started receiving the same error.

Comment: That is very weird. I don't understand how body-tag content could lead to a BeginString error.  Do you know if the DD change alone triggers it, or if it needs to be DD change + fields received?

Comment: @GrantBirchmeier last time it was a change in the fields, we completely removed NoStipulations component fields from the message. The main problem here is that the Logout request is being sent automatically.